# C# DateTime parsing problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have a project created with VS2010. I am running the project from VS2008. Plz note that, I am not running the solution. I am only running the project. Fortunately the solution has only one project.

And in the following line I am having an exception.

```
List<Order> OrderList = new List<Order> {
new Order 
{OrderID = 10248, 
CustomerID = "VINET", 
EmployeeID = 5, 
OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("7/4/2006", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")),
RequiredDate = DateTime.Parse("8/1/2006", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")),
ShippedDate = DateTime.Parse("7/16/2006", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")),
ShipVia = 3, Freight = 32.3800M, ShipName = "Vins et alcools Chevalier",
ShipCountry = "France", 
Order_Details = new List<Order_Detail>(), 
Customer = new Customer(), 
Employee = new Employee(), 
Shipper = new Shipper()}};
```

The exception is:

```
FormatException was unhandled:
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Stack Trace is:

> NwindObjectsCS.exe!NwindObjectsCS.frmMain.CreateOrderList() Line 142    C#
>           NwindObjectsCS.exe!NwindObjectsCS.frmMain.btnInitializer_Click(object sender = {Text = "Load (&Initializer)"}, System.EventArgs e = {X = 86 Y = 22 Button = Left}) Line 51 + 0xe bytes  C#
>           [External Code] 
>           NwindObjectsCS.exe!NwindObjectsCS.Program.Main() Line 18 + 0x1d bytes   C#
>           [External Code]

What suppose to be the problem?

I have downloaded the code from WROX Web site. The code is from the book "Professional ADO.NET 3.5 with LINQ and the Entity Framework". Author is "Roger Jennings". So there should not be any problem.

It is from 3rd chapter.

Comment: what culture is this running under? I see the create specific for en-US but what is the culture the process runs under? Not sure that it matters.

Comment: My PC setting is "US english".

Comment: So you shouldn't need the CultureInfo bit then. I'm not sure taking it out would help. I got your code to work fine in vs2008. I do not have vs2010 handy right now so I can't test the situation you have there. I'm running it on a en-GB pc. You might see if you can break the problem down further.

Comment: You should at least try to narrow the problem down to the line that is causing the problem. Is it the line containing ("7/16/2006") or is it somewhere else. As it stands the code seems OK. More info is needed.

Comment: @Mike Two - that's bad tip! You should almost always use `CultureInfo` when parsing/formatting dates, or you *will* get errors when you least expect it.

Comment: I have downloaded the code from WROX Web site. The code is from the book "Professional ADO.NET 3.5 with LINQ and the Entity Framework". Author is "Roger Jennings". So there should not be any problem. Why WROX would put such a code on their web site?

Comment: @JMSA - please provide stack trace for the exception. Are you sure the problem is in this code?

Comment: I also tried en-GB. It didn't work. But when I change "7/16/2006" to "16/7/2006" it works irrespective of cultural info.

Comment: For stack-trace see the update.

Comment: Probably had a reason, but why not just use `new DateTime(2006, 7, 4)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this (My machine is set to "en-GB"):-

```
static void Main(string[] _args)
{
  DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("7/4/2006", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
  DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("8/1/2006", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
  DateTime d3 = DateTime.Parse("16/7/2006", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
  System.Console.WriteLine("d1:" + d1.ToString());
  System.Console.WriteLine("d2:" + d2.ToString());
  System.Console.WriteLine("d3:" + d3.ToString());
  System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I get no errors. I then go into control panel, regional settings, customize, change my short date format to yyyy-mm-dd and re-run the prog. It then throws the same exception.
Switching the locale completely doesn't affect it though.

It seems that if you've customised your regional settings for the region specified then it breaks.

Have you customised the "en-US" regional date settings on your machine?

Alternatives.

ParseExact:-

```
DateTime.ParseExact("16/7/2006", "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Kobi's suggestion:-

```
DateTime.Parse("16/7/2006", new CultureInfo("en-GB", false));
```

Comment: This is even in the documentation. I didn't know that one. Sounds horrible. It seems there's a second parameter you can set for that, you may want to add it to your answer.

Comment: This turns out that, this problem is completely unrelated to coding.

Comment: @JMSA, I'm not sure about that, from the MSDN page on the cultureInfo:-
"Culture properties are meant for display, not for round-tripping of data."
They seem to be saying not to do this with it..

@Kobi, Do you mean DateTimeStyles? I don't think that helps.

Comment: @JMSA: Try using `ParseExact` rather than `Parse`. This will allow you to specify the exact format of the date/time string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx

Comment: @Jon - sorry, I referred to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h898a16.aspx

Comment: Thanks, added those in for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

If you launch it in the debugger, it should show you exactly what caused the exception. On a quick glimpse, your date strings seem to be valid for the en-US locale, I can only suspect the issue to be somewhere else (e.g. in the constructor of one of your objects?)

Answer (score 1):

I should think that it is due to your current globalisation settings, and the 7/16/2006 date, and it thinking it is in dd/mm/yyyy format, as the 16th month isn't valid.

At the beginning of your script run this line:

```
MessageBox.Show(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString());
```

What does it show?

Comment: then I agree with Virgil, it's got to be with some constructor in your Customer, Employee or Shipper class

Comment: The code is from the book "Professional ADO.NET 3.5 with LINQ and the Entity Framework". author is "Roger Jennings".

Comment: So there should not be any problem.

Comment: Which chapter is the code from?

If you comment out/remove the contsructors does it work?

Comment: Which one causes it to break? Ie comment out one at a time

Comment: The entire line goes to a break. And pressing F11(Step into) doesn't go forward.

Comment: If u have the code downloaded, u can find it in TestClass.cs->public List<Order> CreateOrderList(){/...}.

Comment: Yeah, I have, and it runs fine for me (Visual C# Express 08), so harder to work out which bit is breaking it.

Comment: The only thing I did have to do is to apply the CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US") to previous DateTime parses, but that is because I am UK based.

Comment: Only way I can think of pinpointing it is to block comment out every line of the function and go through one by one, if they all fail then there is something major wrong, if it's only failing on one line then we need to look at that one line in more detail, as there are 99lines in that function it maybe long process.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have set some uncommon DateFormat specified in your OS regional settings, which is adopted in the CultureInfo you create.
To find out about that try what you get when running

```
new DateTime(2006,7,4).ToString();
```

I can't try on my system, but maybe you can get a "default" CultureInfo without your customizations with

```
OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("7/4/2006", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you parsing a hardcoded datetime rather than constructing it directly:

```
List<Order> OrderList = new List<Order> {
new Order 
{OrderID = 10248, 
CustomerID = "VINET", 
EmployeeID = 5, 
OrderDate = new DateTime(2006, 7, 4),
RequiredDate = new DateTime(2006, 8, 1),
ShippedDate = new DateTime(2006, 7, 16),
ShipVia = 3, Freight = 32.3800M, ShipName = "Vins et alcools Chevalier",
ShipCountry = "France", 
Order_Details = new List<Order_Detail>(), 
Customer = new Customer(), 
Employee = new Employee(), 
Shipper = new Shipper()}};
```

Comment: I have downloaded this code from the WROX website. I don't know why the author has chosen to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Think you need to add a time as well, try adding "07:00 AM" to the date-strings.

Comment: But why I need this? Can u explain a little?